kernel died when I run : dataset = Dataset.from_dict(data_dict)
I am fine-tuning sam model for my dataset containing train_images and train_masks. I am able to create dict, but when calling last command i.e. to load dataset from dict, kernel dies. It happened multiple times. Why the following command does not work?
dataset = Dataset.from_dict(data_dict) 

I tried loading from datasets
import Dataset

it worked but kernel dies when i call it.
I want to fix this so that i can continue fine-tuning the model.


Please don't attach screenshot of codes, infact try to copy it here. It would help others to reproduce your problem. The editor provides a very nice code editor that can be used.

Could be a memory problem. How big is train_images and train_masks?
